# Linking a diagram in a diagram

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I'm working on a pretty big infrastructure diagram and in order not to make it too crowded I'm toggling sub diagrams on-click on the various components.

So I have the main diagram, create a smaller diagram within it, group it, move it to position, and make it toggleable by adding a link like this to the related component:

```
data:action/json, { "actions": [ { "toggle": { "cells": [ "uVp822peLVZ-DzD9V1vX-68" ] } } ] }
```

If I want to edit it I have to move the whole thing away, ungroup it, edit it, regroup it, move it back, and update the link. Bit of a hassle. Plus draw.io is getting really slow by now due to the large amount of data, making it quite annoying to edit.

Is there a better way for this? Ideally, I'd just create a new diagram stored in a separate file and show that, but I haven't found out if that's possible at all.

Comment: I created a number of different drawings for different aspects (of a network structure) and then created a new Google Documents and inserted the drawings one by one into that. If I updated any underlying drawing, documents would advise that there was an update to that specific drawing with a link to update it in documents. Would that works for you?